# How to store data in an index in an ArrayList into Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, readfile

I am new to Java and I am trying to do a calculation using values within a txt file. I have read the txt file, which has 3 tabs, each with three values

I have been able to read the file and get the columns as indices but cannot add the separate values into array. So I want three separate arrays

**Read file method**

```
public void read()
{
    try
    {
        FileReader read = new FileReader(file);

        String line = null;
        while((line = FileReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            a.add(line);
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

**Processing method**

```
private void processor () {
    for (String li : a)
    {
        String[] data = li.split("\\s");

        Index = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
        Customers = Double.parseDouble(data[1]); 
        rateOfBuy = Double.parseDouble(data[2]); 

    }
}
```

Comment: `double rateOfBusiness = rateOfBuy * Customers;`?

Comment: I need to get it per year so if I do that then I can only get the last value within those to multiply which is not correct. I think I need to keep them as strings and put them into an array but not sure how

Comment: So you want every `rateOfBusiness` using every `Customers` and every `rateOfBuy`?

Comment: Yes, I was every Customers using every rateOfBusiness and every rateOfBuy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need another `ArrayList` to store your `rateOfBusiness`. Something like this:

```
String file = "test.txt";
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> rateOfBusiness = new ArrayList<>();  //Define with your other fields
```

Then loop through your data and do the math while adding to the array

```
private void process () {

    for (String li : a)
    {
        String[] data = li.split("\\t");

        Index = Double.parseDouble(data[0]);
        Customers = Double.parseDouble(data[1]);; //per year
        rateOfBuy = Double.parseDouble(data[2]); //per year
        rateOfBusiness.add(Customers*rateOfBuy);  //Do math and store for that customer
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Even though this solves your problem, I would look into learning some Object Oriented principles. IsaacShiffman (or Lvl 9 Oddish, or whatever his name is) has a start on how you would solve this going that direction. Makes your code a lot easier to follow and debug.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. This just returns 0.0. I want for it to calculate rateOfBusiness for every year. E.g. my data has three values for each. So should calculate rateOfBusiness for all three

Comment: This seems like a lazy solution. It would better to actually use object oriented principles than just throw in another ArrayList.

Comment: I do agree with you @IsaacShiffman. OP is new though and I didn't learn OO principals till later on (after doing a bunch of general list and array tutorials) which is why I chose this approach (not out of laziness). You seem to already have that solution as well. What good will it do if both of us have the same solution? If OP wants to go that route she can utilize your solution and can ignore my _lazy_ solution.

Comment: Touche. I guess Im just salty because I spent a while answering a vague question and my answer didnt get picked lol...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you are thinking about your data structures correctly. If I were you I would think about this a little differently. To me it makes the most sense just to use a simple array. To handle the complexity  of the three columns, I would create a new class called CustomerRate or something to that effect. I would then make the data into instance variables belonging to instances of that class. That way you could just have a simple array of CustomerRate objects and then access the data stored by each of those objects. This will probably be a lot simpler to deal with overall too.

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish but I'll do my best to help
You would create your new class to be something like this:
your new class:

```
   //This is your new class
   public class CustomerRate {
        private int person;
        private double rate;

        //constructor
        public CustomerRate(int person, double rate) {
            this.person = person;
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        //add appropriate getters and setters and whatever else you need
        public double getRate() {
           return rate;
        }
    }
```

Use the data your parse from your file to create new CustomerRate Objects. Create an array of your objects. Note that this is just an example with one entry with random numbers I'm going to use so you will have to get the loop and parse working:

```
//creating an example customer
CustomerRate customer1 = new CustomerRate(100, 0.5);

//create your collection to store your customer data that you will add/parse
List<CustomerRate> myList = new ArrayList<CustomerRate>();

//adds to list
myList.add(customer1);

//gets element at index and then grabs the rate
double exampleCustomerRate;
exampleCustomerRate = myList.get(0).getRate();
```

I coded this quickly so I may have made some mistake but I hope that gives you the general idea of what you should do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! Would it be possible for you to give me an example of how this would work? as I am new to Java so while I understand what you mean, I am unsure as to how I would implement this.